# How to give notification to the user if a wifi network is not available in android

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me how to give a notification to the user if a wifi network is not available in android, like broad cast receiver in android? Can anybody provide an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a tutorial to do this, it can do these things:](http://silverballsoftware.com/android-monitor-wifi-state-with-broadcastreceiver)

- Is WiFi available on the device
- Is the WiFi enabled Is the WiFi
- Connected to an access point

The gist of it is :

```
private class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
Log.d(tag, "Inside Broadcast Reciever");
CheckWifiStatus();
}
}

private void RegisterWifiWatcher()
{
    if(wifiWatcher == null)
    wifiWatcher = new ConnectionChangeReceiver();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(wifiWatcher, intentFilter);
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error in this line  registerReceiver(wifiWatcher, intentFilter);  can anybody tell what is problem

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following code:

```
public final boolean isWiFiOn() {
    ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if ((connec != null) && ((connec.getNetworkInfo(1) != null)
        && (connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING
            || connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || connec
            .getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.SUSPENDED)) {// To
        // check
        // WiFi
        // connection

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    }
```

Hope this would help.